# Accessing camera in IOS Simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my application, I have a preview option to show video captured in iPhone(camera), I am using now iPhone simulator, Is it possible to capture video frame in iPhone simulator and show it in any view. As I am new to this, I don't have any idea where to start. Any tutorial or link is very helpful...

thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So far apple iPhone simulator don't have feature to connect to the system camera. Only way to see working camera application is to use real device

Answer (score 8):

As iDroid said, there doesn't seem to be a way (here's the corresponding doc, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/125-Using_iOS_Simulator/ios_simulator_application.html). Googling it, however, has produced a possible workaround:

https://web.archive.org/web/20130205102153/http://www.adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/04/using-the-camer-of-ios-simulators.php